# Issue with LWC Flow Navigation

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, navigation

I have an LWC embedded in a flow that has a custom footer. Whenever to click on the custom buttons to navigate the next screen, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Action failed:
> flowruntime:flowRuntime$controller$handleNavigate [The 'NEXT'
> navigation option isn't supported on this screen. Replace it with one
> of the available navigation options: FINISH.]

Not sure how or why I am getting the error when the 'NEXT' option is in this.availableActions. The flow navigates to the next screen but I still get the error. The weirdest part is that it complains about the opposite if I try to use 'FINISH'.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```js
let navigationEvent;

if (this.availableActions.find(action => action === "FINISH")) {
    navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
} else if (this.availableActions.find(action => action === "NEXT")) {
    navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
}

try {
    this.dispatchEvent(navigationEvent);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: is the component exposed to Flow screen using `<target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>` in meta xml?

Comment: Yes, it is. The component is currently being used with a flow.

Comment: We are having the exact same issue. Salesforce support has escalated to R&D and we are waiting for their response.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Peter, do you have a case number for that?

Comment: @user76556 Were you able to solve your issue? I am getting an issue when dispatching 'FlowNavigationFinishEvent' on the click of a 'button in the LWC component. When I click on the button, It shows '[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.' after dispatching the event.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are still looking for answer to this question but using documentation provided here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation

I was able to make flow actions work using following code:

```js
    handleButtonClick(event) {
        var actionClicked = event.target.name;
        var navigationEvent;
    
        if (actionClicked === 'Next') {
            navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
        } else if (actionClicked === 'Finish') {
            navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
        } else if (actionClicked === 'Pause') {
            navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationPauseEvent();
        } else if (actionClicked === 'Back') {
            navigationEvent = new FlowNavigationBackEvent();
        }
    
        try {
            this.dispatchEvent(navigationEvent);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log('Exception: ' + ex);
        }
    }
```

Call above JS function on button click and pass in name. Your button should look like:

```html
    <button onclick={handleButtonClick} id="Back" name="Back" title="Back">Back</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do we remove the custom footer and use the above buttons instead?

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to have the navigation options you want to fire selected in the navigation options