# Example of LWC Custom Flow Navigation Footer

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, navigation

Does anyone know of a sample LWC that can be used as a custom navigation footer for a Screen Flow? I'm looking through blog posts and forums and am finding all Aura components. Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to give a proper answer but I found this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/50.0/lwc/lwc.use_build_for_flow_screens (notice it's api 50, not 51 for some reason) and also this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation and also this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296420/550 - hopefully that'll help a bit.